# worry vs worries

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, academia

> I saw them go through unemployment and **worry about** putting food on the table.
>   I saw them go through unemployment and **worries of** putting food on the table.

Which is grammatically correct?

Comment: I believe both are correct but say the same thing in different ways. The second says you saw them go through two things: A and B. The first says you saw them go through the first, A, and *also* saw B. A tough time overall.

Comment: Thank you so much. That helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a coordination of plain infinitival verb phrases functioning as complement to *saw*:

> I saw them...
>
> go through unemployment
>
> worry about putting food on the table

The second is a coordination of noun phrases functioning as object to preposition *through*:

> I saw them go through...
>
> unemployment
>
> worries of putting food on the table

Both are grammatical.